# How to extract an equation behind the trained DNN model using tf.keras

Tags: neural-network, regression, tf.keras

Is it possible to extract an equation behind the trained model using Keras/Tensorflow with multiple hidden layers and 64 neurons. For example I have two input variables x1 and x2 and ine outout variable y. After training DNN model, I want to build an equation as: y_hat =bias + w1*x1 + w2*x2
For example [as here:][1]

It does not work with more hidden layers as:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(normalizer)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
weights = model.layers[4].get_weights()[0]
biases = model.layers[4].get_weights()[1]
y_hat = bias + w1*x1 + w2*x2
```